# Dialog.show does not display with Codename One, NetBeans and Java

Tags: java, netbeans-7.4

using NetBeans 7.4 and Java, Dialog.show("x","y","YES","NO"); won't display. I'm following Codename One's Hello World demo as an example.

Comment: Post the code here. We have no idea what Codename One is and where you copied your code from.

Answer (score 1):

Codename One seems to be a Java framework for generating platform independent UIs for mobile devices. I just downloaded the plugin for Netbeans 7.4 via Tools->Plugins.

I generated a demo project from scratch and looked through the code.
There is a class in the package **userclasses** called **StateMachine**. I put your code sample into the **initvars** method. Looks now like this:

```
protected void initVars(Resources res) {
    Dialog.show("x","y","YES","NO");
}
```

Running this little demo, I got the dialog shown instantly.
Hope this helps.